Generation of .SO's During .NET MAUI Build
My MAUI project is ONLY Android.  Yet, when I build, there is a sequence in which it seems to be generating a .SO file for each and every assembly...
...
1>[62/82] System.Memory.dll -> System.Memory.dll.so
1>[63/82] System.ObjectModel.dll -> System.ObjectModel.dll.so
1>[64/82] System.Net.Sockets.dll -> System.Net.Sockets.dll.so
1>[65/82] System.Net.Requests.dll -> System.Net.Requests.dll.so
1>[66/82] System.Net.Http.dll -> System.Net.Http.dll.so
1>[67/82] System.Runtime.Loader.dll -> System.Runtime.Loader.dll.so
1>[68/82] System.Numerics.Vectors.dll -> System.Numerics.Vectors.dll.so
1>[69/82] System.Private.Xml.dll -> System.Private.Xml.dll.so
1>[70/82] System.Private.Uri.dll -> System.Private.Uri.dll.so
1>[71/82] System.Net.Ping.dll -> System.Net.Ping.dll.so
1>[72/82] System.Runtime.dll -> System.Runtime.dll.so
...
...
etc., etc., etc.

What is the reason for these .so files being generated?

I assume the .so files contain the Ahead Of Time (AOT) compiled code (thus arm64 code instead of .net byte code). That decreases loading and execution time. For iOS AOT compiled libs were already default with Xamarin, as Apple did not allow runtime interpreted code.

@Robert : So turning off AOT will prevent this?  It really slows down the build ...

This is because the .dll files like System.Memory.dll are used on Windows with C#. While you are running on Android which is based on Linux kernel, the compiler will automatically convert the .dll file to an Android-compatible file: .so(shared object) file which is typically used in Linux environments when using these .dll files. That's why these .so files are being generated.

May : Only for release builds?

@DAConsulting Thanks for your response. I think it'll also exists in debug builds if your project uses these assemblies. :)
